# Which entriey does a Card Verifiable Certificate contain?

Tags: certificates, smartcard

Which entries e.g. public key, valid until, etc. does a CVC has and where can I find a good explanation of this elements? - also with the size, which an entry and related to that, which size the certificate has. (I read a paper where a X.509 certificate was defined with about 2kB)

I found the ISO/IEC 7816 Smart Card Standard but I don't know if it contains the necessary information.

I also found some general information about the entries:

- CA
- certificate owner
- evtl. Accessrights
- public key
- valid until

And the last point, how are the access rights managed, are these also entries with key-value pairs?